# IBMi CL Command - Initialize List of Elements

Tags: ibm-midrange

**Code extract:**

```
             PARM       KWD(ADDLIBL) TYPE(LIBL) MIN(1) LISTDSPL(*INT2) +
                          PROMPT('Additional Libraries')
 LIBL:       ELEM       TYPE(*NAME) LEN(6) MIN(0) RSTD(*YES) +
                           SPCVAL((*FIRST) (*LAST) (*NONE)) PROMPT('Position')
             ELEM       TYPE(*NAME) LEN(10) MIN(0) MAX(10) PROMPT('Libraries')
```

**Question:**

Other than registering a "Validity Checking Program (VLDCKR)" program, is it possible to validate that "Libraries" contains a value when either *FIRST or *LAST is specified (DEP Keyword)?

Comment: Hard to be sure without seeing all of the command, but it looks as if those two ELEMs would be better separated into two PARMs. That could make it easier to test dependencies in the command source, as well as making the data structure simpler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DEP statements can only check the first value of a specified parameter. If you want to do syntax checking for a parameter that accepts a list of values or a parameter with multiple elements or qualifiers, a validity checking exit program can be written to do a third level of syntax check for the command string.  Ref http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_72/cl/dep.htm

It looks like you need to [write a validity checker](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_72/rbam6/wvchk.htm?lang=en).